# Jquery change extension on link on fly

Tags: jquery

I have set of link in so many pages.
Eg:

```
<ul>
 <li> <a href="someurl/somefile.html"> Some file </a> </li>
 <li> <a href="someurl/somefile1.html"> Some file1 </a></li>
 <li> <a href="someurl/somefile2.html"> Some file2 </a></li>
</ul>

<a href="someurl/someotherfile.html"> Some Other file </a>
<a href="someurl/someotherfile1.html"> Some Other file1 </a>
```

Now, I want to change `html` to `php` extension. without modifying the `php` code.

I have tried following code but it does not work.

```
$('a').each(function() {
        $(this).html( $(this).html().replace( ".php", '.html' ) );
 });
```

Any help will be appreciated .

Answer (score 4):

You have two issues in your code:

1) You need to modify attribute href and not html of elements

2) You have swapped the arguments for replacing html with php. first argument should be for match and second one for its replacement.

```
$('a').attr('href',function(i,oldhref) {
    return oldhref.replace( ".html",'.php');
});
```

**Working Snippet:**

```js
$(function(){
$('a').attr('href',function(i,oldhref) {
    return oldhref.replace( ".html",'.php');
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul> 
 <li> <a href="someurl/somefile.html" target="_blank"> Some file </a> </li>
 <li> <a href="someurl/somefile1.html" target="_blank"> Some file1 </a></li>
 <li> <a href="someurl/somefile2.html" target="_blank"> Some file2 </a></li>
</ul>

<a href="someurl/someotherfile.html" target="_blank"> Some Other file </a>
<a href="someurl/someotherfile1.html" target="_blank"> Some Other file1 </a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `replace` as below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a').each(function() {
    $(this).attr('href',$(this).attr('href').replace('html','php') );
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li> <a href="someurl/somefile.html"> Some file </a> 
  </li>
  <li> <a href="someurl/somefile1.html"> Some file1 </a>
  </li>
  <li> <a href="someurl/somefile2.html"> Some file2 </a>
  </li>
</ul>

<a href="someurl/someotherfile.html"> Some Other file </a>
<a href="someurl/someotherfile1.html"> Some Other file1 </a>
```

Comment: Anytime.. Happy coding.. :) I feel you should've accepted @MilindAnantwar's answer.. As its simple and elegant..

Answer (score 0):

You should use,

```
$('a').each(function() {
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    href = href.replace(".php", '.html') ;
    $(this).attr("href", href);
});
```

**Hope this answer will help you.**

Answer (score 0):

> Try with this code.

```
var href = $(this).attr('href');
href = href.replace( ".php", '.html' ) ;
$(this).attr("href", href);
```