# How to find and replace some content using jquery?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have set of following links in so many pages.

Following are the php file which have code .i.e.:

Input :

```
  <a href="someurl/someotherfile.html"> Some Other file </a>
  <a href="someurl/someotherfile1.html"> Some Other file1 </a>
  <p><a href="someurl/someotherfile2.html"> Some Other file2 </a></p>
  <div><a href="someurl/someotherfile2.html"> Some Other file2 </a></div>
  <span><a href="someurl/someotherfile2.html"> Some Other file2 </a></span>
```

Output :

```
  <a href="someurl/someotherfile.php"> Some Other file </a>
  <a href="someurl/someotherfile1.php"> Some Other file1 </a>
  <p><a href="someurl/someotherfile2.php"> Some Other file2 </a></p>
  <div><a href="someurl/someotherfile2.php"> Some Other file2 </a></div>
  <span><a href="someurl/someotherfile2.php"> Some Other file2 </a></span>
```

Now, I want to change the html to php extension in href attribute. without modifying the php code.

I have try following code but it does not work. Noting to happen in this code.

```
$('a').each(function() {
    $(this).html( $(this).html().replace( ".php", '.html' ) );
});
```

Comment: what is the problem??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery change extension on link on fly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37718477/jquery-change-extension-on-link-on-fly)

Answer (score 4):

Try:

Use `attr('href',value)` to set new href and use `.replace` to replace html to php

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('a').each(function() {
    $(this).attr('href',$(this).attr('href').replace( ".html", '.php'));
  });
});
```

Comment: Explanation: because `.html()` is the text inside the element, not it's href property.

Answer (score 0):

`.html()` changes the content inside the `<a>` tag not the content inside the `href` you need to change the `href` value.

```js
$('a').each(function() {
  $(this).attr('href', $(this).attr('href').replace(".html", ".php"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="someurl/someotherfile.html"> Some Other file </a>
<a href="someurl/someotherfile1.html"> Some Other file1 </a>
<p><a href="someurl/someotherfile2.html"> Some Other file2 </a>
</p>
<div><a href="someurl/someotherfile2.html"> Some Other file2 </a>
</div>
<span><a href="someurl/someotherfile2.html"> Some Other file2 </a></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should write:-

```
$('a').each(function() {
    var hrefVal = $(this).attr('href');
    $(this).prop("href", hrefVal.replace( ".html", '.php' ) ); 
});
```

Check this link [prop vs attr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr).

Answer (score 0):

You can change url while a link to be clicked. Clear JS seems to be faster

```
function replaceHref() {
    this.href = this.href.replace('.html','.php');
    return true;
};
window.onload = function() {
    var arr = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
    for(i=0; i < arr.length; i++)
          arr[i].onclick = replaceHref;
};
```